# Equation of a subspace given basis

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Suppose we have a subspace expressed as the linear combination of two vectors (basis):

$S = x * (3, -3, 1) + y * (5, 1, 3)$

How can I find the equation for the subspace (in this case, a plane equation)?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* All vectors in $S$ are perpendicular to the normal of the plane.

Comment: Is the normal equal to the cross-product of the basis' vectors? So the plane would be equal to the all vectors V such that the dot product of V and N is 0?

Comment: @RodrigoStv, yes.

Comment: thanks. Really like the way you answered with a good hint.